# How to mix javascript with razor code

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, syntax

What the syntax to add the following javascript within my razor (chtml) template?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(function(){ 
    @if(Model.IsModalShown)
    {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
 });

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){ 
    @if(Model.IsModalShown)
    {
        <text>$('#myModal').modal('show');</text>
    }
});

</script>
```

OR

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){ 
    if('@Model.IsModalShown' == 'True')
    {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
});

</script>
```